# Cursor custom image not appearing correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, cursor, html5-video

I have a problem with the custom cursor image when hovering over a video element.

HTML

```
<video id="videoPlayer">
  <source src="video/sanaa-faizal.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="video/sanaa-faizal.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

SCRIPT

```
<script>
  var videoPlayer = document.getElementById('videoPlayer');
  // Auto play, half volume.
  videoPlayer.volume = 1;
  // Play / pause.
  videoPlayer.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (videoPlayer.paused == false) {
      videoPlayer.pause();
      videoPlayer.firstChild.nodeValue = 'Play';
    } else {
      videoPlayer.play();
      videoPlayer.firstChild.nodeValue = 'Pause';
    }
  });
</script>
```

CSS

```
video {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  cursor: url(../img/icon-play.png), auto;
}
```

Now the custom cursor image does appear correctly over the video element BUT only when you move the cursor. As soon you stop moving the cursor it goes back to default. Does anybody have a clue how to fix this?

Comment: have you tried wrapping your video element in a div and then applying the cursor style rule to that div? i think the changing frames of the video element might switch the cursor to default. not positive though

Comment: Already tried that, didn't work, and the cursor is already switching back to default even when the video isn't playing.

Comment: I've tested your main code (I added sample source files and a play icon, just for online testing) in a [pen](https://codepen.io/CrisMVP3200/pen/ZXMXqp), and according to that, is working fine, your issue is not present. Aside from the files, am I missing something?